# How to get docker to build this file?

Tags: docker

[image: Error]

Every time I use this command line to get docker to build, I keep getting the errors shown the the powershell window.

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3797320125/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
> PS C:\Users\mark404> docker build -t C:\Usersnode-lafs-web .

Do I need to include a path or something? How would I format that? If its not that... what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

-t specifies the image name/tag.  The . tells Docker that the current directory you are in is the build context and the default location to search for the Dockerfile.

Essentially, you need to run the docker build command from the directory where the Dockerfile resides (though you can specify the full path to the Dockerfile as a parameter if you like).